# CakePHP 2 How to find last record with hasn't related model empty

Tags: cakephp, find

I use `find('first')` with order by `created` field for return last record from table.

But I would like return last record if his related model isn't empty.

It is possible?

**Edit:**
I add code, but doesn't work:

```
$last_project = $this->Project->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'COUNT(ProjectPhoto.id) >' => 0),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'project_photos',
            'alias' => 'ProjectPhoto',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Project.id = ProjectPhoto.project_id'))),
    'order' => 'Project.created DESC'));
```

Comment: This question is really vague, you should give code for what exactly you are doing.  However, it sounds like you want to take a look at writing your own join, with the type set to "inner"

Comment: Post error messages, please.  I would think though that that count in your condition is giving you a problem.  That will basically just tell you how many rows you're getting.  The inner join type should make it so that it will only return rows that contain results from both tables.